# Define an item order in the list

Tags: sorting, sharepoint-2010

I have items in a list. I would like to add a number field that would indicate the order of the items in the list. Is it possible to do it ? I can't find any option like that.

In fact, it seems that the "Change Order" option available in all previous SP version is missing in SP 2010.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is about programming related question, your question is purely product related. You might want to check out sharepoint.stackexchange.com for Sharepoint related questions.

Answer (score 0):

The custom order is still available via the list views.

You could create your own field for a list and set the list sort order in your view to use that field. Then you can choose descending or ascending order.

Comment: yes but I have hundred items that I want to rank, it can be hard to add an item on top as I will have to modify ALL the ranks. In fact, the option I need is exactly the "Change Order" available in the Links list template. I don't understand why it is not available with other templates